# Issues adding SKSpriteNode in SKScene initWithSize method in landscape orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

When trying to add a SKSpriteNode at position 0,0 in my scenes initWithSize method, it is offset on the x axis.  This is due to the positions still holding values for "portrait" orientation.

I've followed the advice in the following [article](http://www.ymc.ch/en/ios-7-sprite-kit-setting-up-correct-scene-dimensions) by adding my scene in the "viewWillLayoutSubviews" method of the view controller, but I'm still experiencing an offset issue.

Here is the initWithSize method:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    

if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES; 

    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0f, -1.0f);

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

    SKSpriteNode *n1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor blueColor] size:CGSizeMake(size.width,20)];
    n1.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    n1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:n1.size];
    n1.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = catCategory;
    n1.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

    n1.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = floorCategory;
    [self addChild:n1];

}
return self;
```

}

Following [Ray Wanderlich's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51108/build-spaceinvaders-in-spritekit-part-2-of-2) article I was able to achieve success by using an offset, and applying it to the position when adding the sprite, but there HAS to be a better way, right?

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
float center = 240.0;

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && IS_WIDESCREEN) {
    center = 284.0;
}
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES; 

    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0f, -1.0f);

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

    SKSpriteNode *n1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor blueColor] size:CGSizeMake(size.width,20)];
    n1.position = CGPointMake(center, 0);
    n1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:n1.size];
    n1.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = catCategory;
    n1.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

    n1.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = floorCategory;
    [self addChild:n1];

}
return self;
```

}

I'd like to find a comprehensive solution that doesn't rely on a hard-coded offset, and will work with landscape orientation regardless of if its an iPad or iPhone.

Thanks.

Comment: there should not be such an offset if the sprite pos is at 0,0 it should be in the lower left corner regardless of where the scene is created, what the orientation or device is. I suspect your issue is where you create the scene in the viewcontroller, could you post that code? Also check that the view is correctly positioned in IB, and verify that this isn't simply due to using the wrong scene scalemode.

Comment: Sure, here is the viewDidLoad and viewWillLayoutSubviews of the view controller:

`- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
  
    
}

-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
    
    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene *scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
   

}`

Comment: Okay, you aren't checking whether skview.scene is nil before presenting the scene, that's going to be a problem. Search here for correct solutions.